How to Create a Managed Table in Apache Hive 4.0.1?
I am running Apache Hive 4.0.1 using Docker with the following command:
docker run -d -p 10000:10000 -p 10002:10002 --env SERVICE_NAME=hiveserver2 --name hive4 apache/hive:4.0.1

After starting Hive, I created a table using the following SQL command:
CREATE TABLE FOO(foo string);

When I check the table definition using:
SHOW CREATE TABLE `default`.`FOO`;

I see that the table is defined as EXTERNAL. However, I want to create a managed table (also referred to as an "internal" table).
What steps should I follow or what specific commands should I use to ensure that the table is created as a managed table in Hive 4.0.1?
Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
